# create multiple pdf by id with TCPDF codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, foreach, tcpdf

good evening ! I need your help, I am trying to generate several PDFs with the TCPDF, I have been able to create a PDF one by one by passing the ID of the database to the function, but what I need is for it to automatically create several PDFs for each ID that it brings from the database, how can I achieve this?

Controller:

```
public function reportpdf($id){
    ob_start();
    
    
        $allowance= $this->allowance_m->get_allowance_byid($id);
        $this->load->library('tcpdf');
        $pdf = new
        TCPDF('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF-8',false);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->setXY(12,40);
        $txt_pembuka = 'Allowance Report';
        //$pdf->SetFontSize(16);
        $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 16, '', 'false');
        $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $txt_pembuka, 0, 'C', 0, 2, '', '', true);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12, '', 'false');
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Nama");
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$allowance->tarjeta);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Periode");
        $periode = strtotime($allowance->monto);
        $formatperiode = date('F Y',$periode);
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$formatperiode);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Uang Makan");
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   Rp.".$allowance->nombre);
        $pdf->Output();

    ob_end_flush();
    }
```

Model:

```
public function get_allowance_byid($id)
    {
        
         $db6 = $this->load->database('db6', TRUE);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE tarjeta='".$id."'";
        return $db6->query($sql)->row();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create "several PDFs for each ID" it is recommended to first save the created PDF files in a local folder on your server before making them available to your user instead of prompting the created PDF directly in the browser as in your example. It is not practical to send multiple PDFs at once to the browser.

Add a path and a filename to the Output Method to save the PDF, preferably with an ID so you can find it again:

```
$pdf->Output('allowance_report_'.$id.'.pdf');
```

Documentation: https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Output

In your case, you can either create multiple PDFs inside the method `reportpdf()` or make a new method for each file.

If you choose to do it inside your current method you can do something like:

```
public function reportpdf($id){

    $allowance= $this->allowance_m->get_allowance_byid($id);
    $this->load->library('tcpdf');

    //CREATE YOUR FIRST PDF....
    $pdf = new
    TCPDF('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF-8',false);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    ... ETC ...

    // SAVE THE FIRST PDF BY PROVIDING A PATH AND A FILENAME 
    $pdf->Output('folder/allowance_report_'.$id.'.pdf');

    //CREATE YOUR SECOND PDF....
    $pdf = new
    TCPDF('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF-8',false);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    ... ETC ...

    // SAVE THE SECOND PDF BY PROVIDING A PATH AND A FILENAME 
    $pdf->Output('folder/another_report_'.$id.'.pdf');

}
```

If you then want to send the PDFs to the browser I suggest you create a zip file containing all the created PDFs and prompt it through the browser.